# Understanding MOSFET Transfer Characteristics

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, logic-level

I am trying to build a control board to turn on and off various 12v devices with a 3.3v logic.

In my hunt for the right MOSFET (have use AO3400 for smaller LED), I'm now looking for something that can pass ideally 10a at 12v with a 3.3v logic. I do have a 5v rail available so I could drive a higher voltage FET with a transistor if necessary; however, I would rather not add extra components.

I'm trying to understand the graphs and wonder if anyone can confirm my thoughts. See below fig. 3 for a IRLZ44NPbF. Considering ambient temperature will not exceed 25c and a 3.3v gate voltage, would I expect to be able to pass roughly 12-13 amps? Or am I reading it wrong?

[image: IRLZ44NPbF From datasheet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use this graph to work out what the power dissipation of the [MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567217c32725) is. I've added red-lines for 10 amps when driven with a VGS of 4 volts and green lines for 3 volt drive: -

[image]

With a 4 volt gate drive and 10 amps flowing, the device would dissipate around 2.2 watts because of the poor on-resistance of this device. If the gate drive was more like 5 volts then dissipation at 10 amps might be under 2 watts but, if you have several of these drivers in close proximity then there will be a lot of heat that will warm up the local ambient temperature around the MOSFETs and, this might be a serious problem without a decent heatsink.

With a 3 volt gate drive, the voltage dropped between drain and source will be about 0.33 volts and, the power dissipated will be 3.3 watts. Maybe at a 3.3 volt gate drive, the power dissipated will be 2.7 watts. Far too much I reckon. I'd be choosing a better MOSFET.

> *I'm trying to understand the graphs and wonder if anyone can confirm
> my thoughts, see below fig 3 for a IRLZ44NPbF, considering ambient
> temperature will not exceed 25c and a 3.3v gate voltage i would expect
> to be able to pass roughly 12-13 amps? or am i reading it wrong?*

- It's the wrong graph to use to determine how much current can be controlled.
- The graph indicates where not to use the MOSFET i.e. at gate-source voltages below about 3.3 volts for switching applications (so you are borderline for thermal runaway at 3.3 volts).
- Local ambient temperature will **certainly** rise above 25°C.

Comment: The  confusion is the image you posted doesn't equate the gate voltage on one of the axis, what does the 0.22v mean that you have outlined?

Comment: @robbrown92 each line on that picture is for a certain gate voltage. I have picked the line that corresponds with a 4 volt gate-source drive level but, of course you are driving it at 3.3 volts so, it will be somewhat worse than the 2.2 watts power dissipation I mentioned. I'll make that clearer in my answer of course. The X axis is drain-source volt-drop. Ideally you want this to be zero.